# What is a chunked request in OpenTSDB?

Tags: http, opentsdb

I'm using Qt4 to post some data points to a OpenTSDB server, which doesn't supports chunked HTTP requests.

The code is basically this:

```
QNetworkRequest request(m_url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QString("application/json"));
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, jsonRequest.toAscii().size());
m_networkAccessManager.post(request, jsonRequest.toAscii());
```

jsonRequest is a QString containing the data points. This code is called from time to time to upload data to the server, and it usually works fine. However, sometimes I receive an error from openTSDB stating that "Chunked request not supported.". 
This seems to happen when the request gets a little bigger (and by bigger, I mean some KB of data).

edit:
I've done a tcpdump of the request when the problem arises, and in fact it doesn't seen to be chunked:

```
POST /api/put HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 14073
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en,*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: 192.168.xx.xxx:xxxx

[{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736269427,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736280628,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736291637,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736302748,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736313840,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736325011,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736336039,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736347182,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736358210,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736369372,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736380401,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736385286,"value":0,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736385286,"value":10,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"2","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736385286,"value":7,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"3","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736385287,"value":6,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"4","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736385287,"value":13,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736385287,"value":99,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"2","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736385287,"value":102,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"3","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736385287,"value":93,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"4","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.transactionsNotDeciphered","timestamp":1420736385287,"value":0,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736391436,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736402608,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736413642,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736424676,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736435823,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736446850,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736458007,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736469060,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736480207,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736491418,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736502620,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736513638,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736524682,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736535712,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736546742,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736557834,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736568858,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736579932,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736590966,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736601993,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736613183,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736624357,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736635387,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736646414,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736657493,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736668624,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736679743,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736685286,"value":0,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736685286,"value":8,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"2","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736685286,"value":9,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"3","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736685295,"value":5,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"4","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736685295,"value":4,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736685295,"value":88,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"2","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736685295,"value":130,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"3","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736685296,"value":123,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"4","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.transactionsNotDeciphered","timestamp":1420736685296,"value":0,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736690786,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736701910,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736712968,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736723999,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736735075,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736746106,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736757266,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736768455,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736779473,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736790606,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736801633,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736812713,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736823740,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736834856,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736845958,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736857103,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736868216,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736879292,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736890320,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736901503,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736912608,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736923761,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736934850,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736946033,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736957061,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736968223,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736979256,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736985284,"value":0,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736985285,"value":16,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"2","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736985285,"value":9,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"3","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tags_read","timestamp":1420736985285,"value":11,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"4","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736985285,"value":9,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736985285,"value":162,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"2","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736985285,"value":166,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"3","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.tag_transactions","timestamp":1420736985285,"value":157,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","antenna":"4","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.transactionsNotDeciphered","timestamp":1420736985286,"value":0,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420736990353,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420737001532,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420737012658,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420737023691,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420737034823,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420737045906,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420737056942,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},{"metric":"slt.reader.temperature","timestamp":1420737068032,"value":56,"tags":{"sltId":"5036","readerId":"1","host":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}]HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 1080
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 17:18:43 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html><head><meta http-equiv=content-type content="text/html;charset=utf-8"><title>Bad Request</title>
<style><!--
body{font-family:arial,sans-serif;margin-left:2em}A.l:link{color:#6f6f6f}A.u:link{color:green}.subg{background-color:#e2f4f7}.fwf{font-family:monospace;white-space:pre-wrap}//--></style></head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff><table border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 width=100%><tr><td rowspan=3 width=1% nowrap><b><font color=#c71a32 size=10>T</font><font color=#00a189 size=10>S</font><font color=#1a65b7 size=10>D</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class=subg><font color=#507e9b><b>Looks like it's your fault this time</b></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table><blockquote><h1>Bad Request</h1>Sorry but your request was rejected as being invalid.<br/><br/>The reason provided was:<blockquote>Chunked request not supported.</blockquote></blockquote><table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr><td class=subg><img alt="" width=1 height=6></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

I was thinking Qt was changing to use a chunked request when the request got larger, but it's not the case. So the current question is: what is a chunked request in openTSDB?

Comment: Would it be possible to use an ordinary QTcpSocket? Just an idea in case it turns out you can't any other way. You can point the request to netcat to see how it is formatted.

Comment: Yes, it would. However, as there's already an http client implementation in Qt, I prefer to avoid it, if possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've finally found the reason it thinks my request is chunked: OpenTSDB internally uses Netty for networking, and if Netty reads a block that doesn't contain the complete request, then it's flagged as chunked, even if there's no Transfer-Encoding header in the request.

There are two possible solutions for this:

- adding "tsd.http.request.enable_chunked = true" to the config file, so that it doesn't reject chunked requests and adding "tsd.http.request.max_chunk = " to the config file, and setting it to a sensible size for your requests
- If you can change the client, force it to send smaller requests

Please note that enabling chunked requests for public facing servers may not be a good idea, as a malicious client can send unbounded requests, overloading the server.

Credits goes to irc users jaylr and manolama, who provided me the info on irc channel #opentsdb@freenode.net